# Phonegap: ajax + jsonp working on PC but not in Android

Tags: android, json, cordova, jsonp

Working with Cordova 2.5.0 + jQuery 1.91, I'm trying to parse a remote JSON

```
$.support.cors = true;
$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://sub.foo.com/json.php?callback=?',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data, status){
                alert("OK");
        },
        error: function(){
                alert("Error");
        }
});
```

It works ok on my desktop Chrome browser, but not on my Android emulator ("Error" message).

I did set permissions on 'AndroidManifest.xml'

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

and on 'config.xml'

```
<access origin="http://sub.foo.com" />
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you very much.

Comment: no one? :( i've got your same problem.. have you solved?

Comment: and i have the same problem too

Answer (score 1):

Add following line in res/xml/cordova.xml file

```
<access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/> <!-- allow local pages -->
    <access origin="http://192.168.1.211*" subdomains="true"/>
    <access origin="http://70.38.120.153:240*" subdomains="true"/>
    <!-- <access origin="https://example.com" /> allow any secure requests to example.com -->
    <!-- <access origin="https://example.com" subdomains="true" /> such as above, but including subdomains, such as www -->
    <access origin=".*"/>

    <log level="DEBUG"/>
    <preference name="useBrowserHistory" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
```